# How to run more than one ESB runtime in Mule Studio

Tags: soap, mule

I have 3 Mule Studio projects having one SOAP web service in each of them. One of the service is composite i.e. it will orchestrate services running on different ports in another projects. I am unable to find a way to run all three services on same ESB runtime. If I run first and then try to run second service it gives error "you already have running instance of embedded Mule ESB runtime". Is there any way out to test this scenario inside Mule Studio?

P.S. The reason to separate out services in different projects is to achieve modularity i.e. if I need a change in one service, it won't affect other deployed services.

Comment: you can export all three as Mule zip and deploy in MuleStandalone. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is make another workspace and put that project into that workspace(it will be opened in another window).

how to:

- Open another instance of mule studio
- when the window opens to select your workplace chose another folder or have it create another one(mines workspace 1 and workspace 2)
- move one of your projects into that new workspace by deleting it from your current one and re-importing it into the new mule workspace.

Just as a heads up some of mule shares the same resource for example debugging, mule uses port 6666 for debugging on all instances, so you can only debug on one workspace at a time. you may run into this issue if your projects share a certain resource.

Comment: I also think it is only option to test with real data. But as of now I have created dummy services inside composite project.

Answer (score 0):

Current versions of Anypoint Studio allow to execute more than one application in the same Mule Runtime instance. At this time the current versions are 6.6.x and 7.4.x.

In the menu Run / Run as / Mule Application (Configure) you will see a list of open projects in the box "Mule projects to launch". Just check the projects that you want to run together and click on Run.

Note that is not possible to use different Mule Runtime versions, nor execute them in separate instances.